# can't sum in ggplot for R shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly, bar-chart

I am working on a R shiny app and I am struggling with ggplot.
Here's my dataset :

```
Year = c(2021, 2022,2023,2021,2023,2020,2021,2023,2022,2023,2022,2021,2020,2020,2023)
Country = c("France", "France", "Italy", "England", "Italy", "England", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "France", "France", "Italy", "England", "Italy", "England")
Age = c(22,23,20,24,21,25,21,21,23,24,25,21,20,20,25)
Students = c(1,5,100,43,76,23,43,50,122,5,67,32,53,22,90)
Gender = c("Boy","Girl","Boy","Girl","Boy","Boy","Girl","Girl","Boy","Boy","Girl","Girl","Boy","Girl","Boy") 
df = data.frame(Year, Country, Age, Students, Gender)
```

In the app, the user can choose to filter by age or to display all ages in a ggplot.
[image]

However, ggplot isn't summing Students' values. I don't understand why. How can I tell ggplot to sum values ?

Here's my ggplot code :

```
g <- ggplot(df,
            aes(x=Year, 
                y=Students, 
                fill=Gender))+ 
  geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge')+
  geom_text(aes(label = Students))+
  facet_wrap(~ Country) +
  xlab("")
g <- ggplotly(g)
g
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you could use `stat_summary` or `stat="summary"` both in `geom_bar` and `geom_text` to compute the sum, IMHO the easier option would be to summarise your data outside of `ggplot()`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

df <- df |>
  group_by(Country, Year, Gender) |>
  summarise(Students = sum(Students), .groups = "drop")

g <- ggplot(
  df,
  aes(
    x = Year,
    y = Students,
    fill = Gender
  )
) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(label = Students)) +
  facet_wrap(~Country) +
  xlab("")

ggplotly(g)
```

[image]